# How can I represent tags in BlogML?

Tags: blogengine.net, blogml

I'm writing a little console app to convert the xml export file produced by wordpress backup in to BlogML so I can import it into BlogEngine.NET

But I've hit a bit of stumbling block in that tags don't seem to be supported.

Is there a way I can fake them so they'll get picked up as tags and not categories?

I've upvoted the [issue on codeplex](http://blogml.codeplex.com/workitem/14578), but I seem to be the only one who has, which suggests there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a problem with the Blog ML generated by Blogengine.net. I had attempted to migrate from BE.Net 2.6 to Orchard 1.4. Problems was the tags are not picked up and only the categories are picked up by Orchard as tags. This is obviously not what i want.I have only 4 categories but lots of tags. Base don an email exchanged with Nick Mayne who wrote the Blog ML plug ing for Orchard the Blog ML that BE.net generates is nonstandard. The Blog ML spec does not have tags but does have categories. The exported file from BE has both the tags and categories but Orchard was only picking up the cats. I upvoted that issue earlier.